# XCode customization

Tags: xcode4.3

Where can I find documentation of Xcode's 4.3 configuration/customization features and functions? E.g., where/how do I install templates, editor color scheme, library files etc.  Though I am looking for these specific answers, I would rather much prefer a book/site reference. Browsing Apple's developer site and built-in help is quite far from enlightening to my surprise...